# Shadow deployment for test in production

Tags: testing

As well known, the most important parts of Test In Production (TiP) are:

- Leverage real customer behavior/data
- Mitigate the customer risk.

I found the Shadow Deployment a promising approach.

With this approach, the V-next product is deployed in production side by side with the V-current.
When customer request arrives, a clone of the request is routed to V-next for testing purpose. But the result is never returned to customer. Thus NO risk is exposed to customer.
Once the V-next is ready, we can simply switch to it and tear down the V-current.

So it seems the critical parts are:

- How to implement the routing logic for various kinds of projects,
  such as Web service, Web site, etc.
- How to isolate the data generated
  during the test because it could have side effect for upstream and
  downstream systems in production.

My questions are:

- Is there anything else we need to care?
- And is there any best practice/tools/design/solution to address these concerns?

For the specific technology details, please check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599167/how-to-clone-iis-request-and-redirect-to-a-test-version-site

(Unfortunately, SO community deleted above post...)

Thanks!

Comment: "best practice/tools/design/solution" - that would probably depend on what your current software stack is - you've not given us a clue about what technologies you're currently using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I was planning to keep it not too specific. But I added details now.

Answer (score 5):

We did this at Twitter using [Diffy](https://github.com/opendiffy/diffy/). Not only do you want to capture V-next, you also want to compare it V-current. Further, you want to aggreagate and denoise this comparison over thousands of samples to gain confidence.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach for testing in production is to test on a low percentage of users or to open a new feature only to your QA team on production (dark launches).

There are many tools that can help you test in production, even on real users.
[Configz.io](https://configz.io) is a great tool for that.